# How to know installed cookbooks and their versions on the chef-client?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

How can I know all the installed chef cookbooks and their versions on the chef-client through command line?

Answer (score 1):

Cookbooks are not "installed" on the client. Every time chef-client starts up, it asks the server which version of each cookbook to use. You can see this displayed at the start of the Chef run. You can run the same version solution locally using the `knife-solve` plugin.